# Query Performance of incremental "bigger than"performance vs. separate "between" operator

Tags: sql, database, oracle, query-optimization

I have a query which looks like follow:

```
select         
CASE
WHEN col BETWEEN 0 AND 20 THEN 0
WHEN col BETWEEN 20 AND 50 THEN 20
WHEN col BETWEEN 50 AND 100 THEN 40
WHEN col BETWEEN 100 AND 200 THEN 75
WHEN col BETWEEN 200 AND 10000 THEN 86
ELSE 0 END AS t_col
from TAB1;
```

I wanted to get a better performance and rewrote it to:

```
select case  
WHEN col < 20 then 0
WHEN col < 50 then 20
WHEN col < 100 then 40
WHEN col < 200 then 75
WHEN col < 1000 then 86
END AS t_col
from TAB1;
```

I tought the second query might be faster because not an interval would be created but only the value of column would be compared to one number. The Explain Plan gives me identical results for both queries. i would like to know which one of them do a better performance?

Comment: BETWEEN includes both boundaries, so you'd probably want to use `<=` in the 2nd query. As of performance: run them both and see for yourself. On small data sets, you won't notice any difference. How large is that table?

Comment: All this is done in RAM by CPU, the difference might be in range of nanoseconds. Don't waste your time on this "problem".

Comment: The execution plan is the same because it's not concerned with the SELECT list unless it contains scalar subqueries.

Comment: I suppose the `between` version lets you put the most frequently occurring values first, in theory saving a few cpu cycles. Then again, the second version only requires one comparison per case instead of two. But as @WernfriedDomscheit said, it's unlikely to make a measurable difference for any real-world query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, let me do a PoC and see what happens

```
SQL> create table t1 ( c1 number, c2 varchar2(40) , c3 varchar2(40) ) ;

Table created.

SQL> declare
  2  begin
  3  for i in 1 .. 1000000
  4  loop
  5   insert into t1 values ( round(dbms_random.value(1,100)) , dbms_random.string('X',40) , dbms_random.string('X',40) );
  6  end loop;
  7  end;
  8  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats('TESTUSER','T1');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select count(*) from t1 ;

  COUNT(*)
----------
   1000000
```

**Scenario**

```
SQL> set autotrace traceonly
SQL> select
CASE
WHEN c1 BETWEEN 0 AND 20 THEN 0
WHEN c1 BETWEEN 20 AND 50 THEN 20
WHEN c1 BETWEEN 50 AND 100 THEN 40
WHEN c1 BETWEEN 100 AND 200 THEN 75
WHEN c1 BETWEEN 200 AND 10000 THEN 86
ELSE 0 END AS t_c1
from t1;  2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9

1000000 rows selected.

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 3617692013

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |  1000K|  2929K|  2322   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| T1   |  1000K|  2929K|  2322   (1)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

SQL> select case
WHEN c1 < 20 then 0
WHEN c1 < 50 then 20
WHEN c1 < 100 then 40
WHEN c1 < 200 then 75
WHEN c1 < 1000 then 86
END AS t_c1
from t1;  2    3    4    5    6    7    8

1000000 rows selected.


Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 3617692013

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |  1000K|  2929K|  2322   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| T1   |  1000K|  2929K|  2322   (1)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

They behave identical, right? Not exactly, although the plan looks the same, let's check the statistics. For that I will flush buffer cache and shared pool after each test.

```
SQL> set autotrace traceonly timing on
SQL> select
CASE
WHEN c1 BETWEEN 0 AND 20 THEN 0
WHEN c1 BETWEEN 20 AND 50 THEN 20
WHEN c1 BETWEEN 50 AND 100 THEN 40
WHEN c1 BETWEEN 100 AND 200 THEN 75
WHEN c1 BETWEEN 200 AND 10000 THEN 86
ELSE 0 END AS t_c1
from t1;  2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9

1000000 rows selected.

Elapsed: 00:00:02.92

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 3617692013

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |  1000K|  2929K|  2322   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| T1   |  1000K|  2929K|  2322   (1)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------


Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
         12  recursive calls
          0  db block gets
      72870  consistent gets
       6180  physical reads
          0  redo size
   19435128  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
     733901  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
      66668  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
          3  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
    1000000  rows processed

SQL> alter system flush shared_pool ;

System altered.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.08
SQL> alter system flush buffer_cache ;

System altered.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.04
SQL> select t1.* , case
WHEN c1 < 20 then 0
WHEN c1 < 50 then 20
WHEN c1 < 100 then 40
WHEN c1 < 200 then 75
WHEN c1 < 1000 then 86
END AS t_c1
from t1;  2    3    4    5    6    7    8

1000000 rows selected.

Elapsed: 00:00:03.49

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 3617692013

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |  1000K|    81M|  2323   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| T1   |  1000K|    81M|  2323   (1)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------


Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
         18  recursive calls
          0  db block gets
      72878  consistent gets
       6180  physical reads
          0  redo size
  101747627  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
     733834  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
      66668  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
          3  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
    1000000  rows processed
```

The second one is slower than the first one, probably because of the `recursive calls` done in the second one ( 18 ) against the first one ( 12 ). If you start putting more fields, and the data is huge, I am quite sure you will get better performance in the query with `between` than in the other one.

But obviously, it is just a feeling, you must test yourself in your own database. I am quite sure that the final query contains other fields, where conditions, etc... therefore this answer only covers what you put in the original question, and not what will happen in a real case scenario with many other fields, where conditions, indexes, etc...

Comment: This was a pretty accurat eanswer. I have several of those compare fields and the views are huge. So those secods could some up to minutes.

Comment: thank you @Amir, glad it helped :)

Comment: The additional recursive calls may be related to parsing, as the number becomes 0 when rerunning, in which case the choice of syntax won't have a measurable effect on real-world queries. When I ran the test, the biggest factor by a mile was the SQL\*Plus array size setting, and on repeated runs the only autotrace stats that were different were the bytes sent/received via SQL\*Net, while the timings varied by up to a second presumably due to other processing going on in the system.

Comment: That is clear., once parsing is off the equation. In my answer scenario, nothing was running in the system at that moment, but the test itself. I did several and the first one was always a bit faster than the second. I did not use a 10046 trace event to see what it was really happening behind, though. Anyhow, as I said, it was just a feeling and probably not worth to go into more details without dealing with the real query. I agree with you William that in case of real scenario, the calls become irrelevant as soft parsing will take care of that.

Comment: I just noticed the second version (with `<`) includes `t1.*`, while the one with `between` does not. That might account for the additional parsing calls and longer runtime, as there is more data to fetch.

Answer (score 3):

They are effectively the same. Any tiny difference in CPU cycles will be overshadowed by I/O, network overhead etc required to perform the query.

I suppose the `between` version lets you put the most frequently occurring values first, in theory improving efficiency if a large proportion of the values fall within one or two ranges. Then again, the `<` version only requires one comparison per case instead of two.

I still award the `<` version more style points :)

I tested both versions within a PL/SQL cursor loop to eliminate network issues, and ran the test multiple times. The results were within half a second of each other over 10 million iterations, which is about the same as the variation over multiple runs (because there is *always* something else running on any server or laptop).

```
create table t1 (c1, c2, c3) pctfree 0 nologging
as
select round(dbms_random.value(1,100))
     , cast(dbms_random.string('X',40) as varchar2(40))
     , cast(dbms_random.string('X',40) as varchar2(40))
from   xmltable('1 to 1000000');
```

```
declare
    type test_rectype is record(num number);

    totalTime1 simple_integer := 0;
    totalTime2 simple_integer := 0;

    time1Percentage simple_integer := 0;
    time2Percentage simple_integer := 0;

    function testCursor
        ( cursorNum in integer )
        return sys_refcursor
    is
        testCursor sys_refcursor;
    begin
        if cursorNum = 1 then
            open testCursor for
                select case
                           when c1 < 20 then 0
                           when c1 < 50 then 20
                           when c1 < 100 then 40
                           when c1 < 200 then 75
                           when c1 < 1000 then 86
                       end as t_c1
                from   t1;
        elsif cursorNum = 2 then
            open testCursor for
               select case
                           when c1 < 20 then 0
                           when c1 < 50 then 20
                           when c1 < 100 then 40
                           when c1 < 200 then 75
                           when c1 < 1000 then 86
                       end as t_c1
                from   t1;
        end if;

        return testCursor;
    end testCursor;
      
    -- Fetch all rows from a cursor and return time in hundredths of a second:
    procedure time_cursor
        ( inCursor in sys_refcursor
        , outTime  in out nocopy simple_integer )
    is
        startTime simple_integer := dbms_utility.get_time;
    begin
        -- 21c new iterator syntax
        for r test_rectype in values of inCursor loop
            null;  -- Could also compare rowcounts here
        end loop;

        outTime := dbms_utility.get_time - startTime;

        close inCursor;
    end time_cursor;

    -- Report timing difference:
    procedure print_comparison
        ( time1 simple_integer
        , time2 simple_integer )
    is
    begin
        time1Percentage := 100 * time1 / (time1 + time2);
        time2Percentage := 100 * time2 / (time2 + time2);

        dbms_output.put_line('Between:  '||to_char(time1/100,'900d00')|| rpad(' |',time1Percentage,'|'));
        dbms_output.put_line('LessThan: '||to_char(time2/100,'900d00')|| rpad(' |',time2Percentage,'|'));
    end print_comparison;

    procedure compare_cursors
        ( runningTime1 in out nocopy simple_integer
        , runningTime2 in out nocopy simple_integer )
    is
        testCursor1 sys_refcursor := testCursor(1);
        testCursor2 sys_refcursor := testCursor(2);

        time1 simple_integer := 0;
        time2 simple_integer := 0;

        time1Percentage simple_integer := 0;
        time2Percentage simple_integer := 0;
    begin
        time_cursor(testCursor1, time1);
        time_cursor(testCursor2, time2);

        print_comparison(time1, time2);

        -- Update running totals:
        runningTime1 := nvl(runningTime1,0) + nvl(time1,0);
        runningTime2 := nvl(runningTime2,0) + nvl(time2,0);

        dbms_output.new_line;
    end compare_cursors;
begin
    for i in 1..10 loop
        compare_cursors(totalTime1, totalTime2);
    end loop;

    dbms_output.put_line('Total:'||chr(10));

    print_comparison(totalTime1, totalTime2);
end;
```

```
Between:    02.18 ||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
LessThan:   02.25 |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||

Between:    02.03 |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
LessThan:   02.03 |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||

Between:    02.13 |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
LessThan:   02.13 |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||

Between:    02.13 ||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
LessThan:   02.07 |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||

Between:    02.16 ||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
LessThan:   02.27 |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||

Between:    02.28 |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
LessThan:   02.28 |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||

Between:    02.17 ||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
LessThan:   02.27 |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||

Between:    02.24 ||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
LessThan:   02.30 |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||

Between:    02.24 |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
LessThan:   02.27 |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||

Between:    02.25 ||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
LessThan:   02.18 |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||

Total:

Between:    21.81 |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
LessThan:   22.05 |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
```